# How can I interrupt the IPython interpreter as opened in emacs?

Tags: python, emacs, ipython

Let's say I accidentally evaluate an enormous variable--a list with a ba-jillion elements, or whatever.  As they scroll down my screen and my computer crawls to a halt, is there a good way to interrupt this *without* killing my `*Python*` buffer?  I'm using IPython via `python-mode.el` and `ipython.el` in emacs24 on Mac OS X Leopard--

Thoughts appreciated,
a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually C-c until it stops... and it usually works...

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping for something a bit more reliable--it often takes quite awhile for it to stop.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you could file a feature request at

http://launchpad.net/python-mode

asking for a way how to limit the output displayed

Dunno if its possible, resp. how difficult to implement.