# How to interrupt a runaway ipython evaluation without terminating the parent process?

Tags: python, ipython

***Sometimes*** it happens that an ongoing `ipython` evaluation won't respond to one, [***or even several***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637219#answer-6646806), `Ctrl-C`'s from the keyboard<sup>1</sup>.

Is there some other way to goose the `ipython` process to abort the current evaluation, and come back to its "read" state?

Maybe with `kill -SOMESECRETSIGNAL <pid>`?  I've tried a few (`SIGINT`, `SIGTERM`, `SIGUSR1`, ...) to no avail: either they have no effect (e.g. `SIGINT`), or they kill the `ipython` process.  Or maybe some arcane `ipython` configuration?  Some sentinel file? ... ?

<sup>1</sup><sub>"Promptly enough", that is.  Of course, it is impossible to specify precisely how promptly is "promptly enough"; it depends on the situation, the reliability of the delay's duration, the temperament of the user, the day's pickings at Hacker News, etc.</sub>

Comment: it is extremely unlikely that IPython has anything to do with the lack of responsiveness.  It is most likely a generic Python issue (such as extension code grabbing the GIL), and there isn't much (or anything) you can do about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on where execution is occurring when you decide to interrupt (in a python function, in a lower level library,...).  If this commonly occurs within a function you have created, you can try putting a try/except block in the function and catching `KeyboardInterrupt` exceptions.  It may not break out of a low level library (if that is indeed where you are running) but it should prevent the ipython interpreter from exiting.