# IPython keyboard interrupt CTRL + C inconsistent

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib, ipython

I'm getting inconsistent responses from the Keyboard interrupt <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in interactive python (run in xterm) after plotting from matplotlib.

As expected, when executing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> inside ipython2 I get the `KeyboardInterrupt` message.

However, once I plot anything using matplotlib (specifically matplotlib.pyplot) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will exit the interactive python session, as opposed to exiting the running script in the interactive python session (if there is one).

A primitive example.

```
import numpy as n
import matplotlib.pyplot as m
x = n.linspace(0,4*n.pi,500)
y = x**2*n.sin(x)

m.plot(x,y)
m.show()
```

Preferrable behavior would be for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to always only interrupt a running script (if any is running), instead of the interactive python session itself.

Comment: What does "ran any script from ipython2" mean?

Comment: @user2864740 I attempted to edit for clarity. Essentially I meant that phrase as "executing any script I have written (using 'run script.py') from inside an interactive python session".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to interrupt a runaway ipython evaluation without terminating the parent process?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838061/how-to-interrupt-a-runaway-ipython-evaluation-without-terminating-the-parent-pro)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838061/how-to-interrupt-a-runaway-ipython-evaluation-without-terminating-the-parent-pro

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to detach matplotlib plots so that the computation can continue?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/458209/is-there-a-way-to-detach-matplotlib-plots-so-that-the-computation-can-continue)

Comment: If people are still researching this problem (like me) then the links in the comments above suggest the following answer :
`m.show(0)` or `m.show(block=Flase)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did have the same problem for a long time. Try to run ipython with qt:

```
ipython --matplotlib=qt
```

Comment: Can you be more elaborate on, what is not working for you?